# Coord parameter not working in GeoServer SQL view WFS request

Tags: postgis, geoserver, postgresql, javascript

I try to use coords from two points collected in a JS file in order to send them to a WFS Geoserver request, connected to a SQL view which will create a buffer around the line composed of those two points.

My SQL view works fine with the default values in GeoServer, but I can't manage to have a request (with the exact same parameters values) working from the JS file.

Here is my JS code :

```
url1 = 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/projetgeonum/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=projetgeonum%3A'
url2 = '&maxFeatures=50&outputFormat=application%2Fjson'
var dep_long = "7.14518"
var dep_lat = "43.99156"
var arr_long = "7.342542"
var arr_lat = "43.808902"
params = '&viewparams=dep_long:' + dep_long + ';dep_lat:' + dep_lat + ';arr_long:' + arr_long + ';arr_lat:' + arr_lat
```

Url building function for WFS request:

```
   function url_fun(type) {
        if (type == 'saison') {
            url = url1 + type + url2 + params
            console.log(url)
            return url
        } else if (type == 'milieu') {
            url = url1 + type + url2 + params + ';saison_code:' + user_saison
            return url
        } else if (type == 'sport') {
            url = url1 + type + url2 + params + ';saison_code:' + user_saison + ';milieu_code:' + user_milieu
            return url
        }
    }
```

Here is my SQL view:

```
SELECT DISTINCT saison, saison_code from sport_06
WHERE ST_Intersects(geom,
ST_Buffer(ST_Envelope(ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(%dep_long% %dep_lat%, %arr_long% %arr_lat%)', 4326)),0.01))
```

And here is the result of the preview in GeoServer, which is totally what I want:
[image: GeoJSON obtained]

Here is the url I build in the JS, with the parameters at the end:

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/projetgeonum/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=projetgeonum%3Asaison&maxFeatures=50&outputFormat=application%2Fjson&viewparams=dep_long:7.14518;dep_lat:43.99156;arr_long:7.342542;arr_lat:43.808902
```

And here is the error I get when trying to access this url (which syntax seems totally right for me):

```
<ServiceExceptionReport version="1.2.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/ogc http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.0.0/OGC-exception.xsd">
<ServiceException>
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException java.io.IOExceptionInvalid value for parameter arr_long
</ServiceException>
</ServiceExceptionReport>
```

I tried first to use only one parameter in my SQL view, as `('LINESTRING(%coords%)', 4326)`, where I built the coords parameter such as 'float number float number, float number float number', but I let down this option as I didn't succeed to make GeoServer accept the comma in the middle, despite a backlash.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok i eventually succeeded, the problem with the four parameters was the default regex expression of GeoServer : `^[\w\d\s]+$`
This regex wasn't recognizing the dots in the coords numbers, so I changed it to `^[.\w\d\s]+$` ant it was all sorted!